# Fetch Detail from API in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to display detail tour from data selected but is not working, I already to try like as:

```
const Detail = ({
  match: {
    params: { id },
  },
}) => {
  const fetchTripDetail = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5001/api/v1/trip/${id}`, {});
    return response.json();
  };

  const { tour } = useQuery(["trips", { id }], fetchTripDetail);

  const [number, setPlus] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div className="App-detail">
      <div className="content-detail">
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1>{id}</h1>
        <h4 style={{ color: "grey" }}>{tour.title}</h4>
</div>
</div>
  );
};

export default Detail;
```

but the result like as, can anyone help me?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
Detail
D:/Training/dumbways/dewetour/src/Components/Detail/Detail.jsx:37
> 37 | <h4 style={{ color: "grey" }}>{tour.title}</h4>
```

Comment: You need to handle rendering before the fetch has finished.

Comment: can you modify this code and try? <h4 style={{ color: "grey" }}>{tour?tour.title:null}</h4>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) data properly:

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

I recommend you to fetch data inside an [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. It is created to handle use cases like this.

Example of data fetching using `useEffect` hook:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((body) => setData(body))
      .catch((err) => console.log("error", err));
  }, []);

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
pre { background: #efefef; padding: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your recommendation, but now I can call the field in any JSON?

Comment: Yes, you can assign any JSON to `data` variable and access every field it defines. In my example, I just print whole `data` object but it is possible to print only a part e.g.: `data.userId`.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for `response.json()` because it still a `promise` :

```
const fetchTripDetail = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5001/api/v1/trip/${id}`, {});
  const data = await response.json();
  return data
};
```